# There is given spectrum for $\phi$. Find such $\psi$ with spectrum with special property.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, spectra

> We have spectrum for $\phi$. It is set $X$.   Now, we try to find such
>   formula $\psi$ that its spectrum is $Y=\{n+m|n,m\in X\}$.   It is
>   allowed to extend sygnature.

Being honestly, I can't deal with it, however I managed to solve some simpler problems with finding formula for spectrum.

Since I can't start I state for me other problem:
Find $Y=\{2n|n\in X\}$.
I am not sure if I can **correctly** solve it. However, I try to defeat it.
Lets consider universum of models for $\phi$.  Now, I extend this universum - each element will be matched wit its mirror reflection - whatever what does it mean - we get universum $A'$. More precisely, each element will be have exactly one twinbrother. Then, I add relation $twins(x,y)$ has brother.   Where $x$ is old element and $y$ is new element (added to uniersum $A$).
Then $\psi = \phi\wedge \forall_{x\in A} \exists!_{y\in A'}R(x,y)$

Can anyone check my reasoning, especially I ask for help with base problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your sentence $\psi$ doesn't work. A model of $\psi$ is just a model $A$ of $\phi$ expanded by the binary relation $R$ in such a way that every element $x\in A$ is related to a unique $y\in A$. Since every model of $\phi$ can be expanded in this way (for example, just take $R(x,x)$ for every $x$), the spectrum of $\psi$ is the same as the spectrum of $\phi$.

You could try to fix this by requiring that every $x\in A$ is related to a unique $y\in A$ and $x\neq y$. But then it's exactly the finite models of $\phi$ with even cardinality that can be expanded to models of $\psi$, and the spectrum of $\psi$ is $\{n\mid n\in X\text{ and } n \text{ is even}\}\neq \{2n\mid n\in X\}$.

Instead, you want to realize the following picture: A model of $\psi$ should be a model $A$ of $\phi$, together with a bunch of elements, each one a twin of some element in $A$, but sitting outside $A$. So add a new unary relation symbol $P$ to the language, and try to write down a sentence expressing

1. $\{x\mid P(x)\}$ is a model of $\phi$.
2. $R$ is the graph of a bijection between $\{x\mid P(x)\}$ and $\{y\mid \lnot P(y)\}$.

If you don't see how to do point 1, a key word to look up is *relativization*.

Once you see how to do that, realizing the spectrum $\{x+y\mid x,y\in X\}$ is actually a bit easier. Rather than taking a model of $\phi$ and adding a twin for each of its elements, you just need to set two models of $\phi$ side by side...

Edit 1: Here's a solution to your problem, hidden behind a Spoiler tag, as you requested.

> Let $\phi$ be a sentence with spectrum $X$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be new unary relation symbols. Then $(\forall x\, ((P(x)\lor Q(x)) \land \lnot (P(x)\land Q(x)))) \land \phi^P \land \phi^Q$ (where $\phi^P$ and $\phi^Q$ are the relativizations of $\phi$ to $P$ and $Q$, respectively) has spectrum $\{n+m\mid n,m\in X\}$. This sentence asserts that the predicates $P$ and $Q$ partition the universe, and each picks out a model of $\phi$.

Edit 2: You ask in the comments about relativization. The idea is simple: The relativization $\phi^P$ of a sentence $\phi$ to a unary predicate $P(x)$ is obtained by replacing the quantifiers so they only quantify over the interpretation of $P$. That is, we replace $\forall y\, \psi(y)$ by $\forall y\, (P(y)\rightarrow \psi(y))$, and we replace $\exists y\, \psi(y)$ by $\exists y\, (P(y) \land \psi(y))$. Then you can prove by induction that a structure $A$ satisfies $\phi^P$ and only if the substructure of $A$ with domain $P$ satisfies $\phi$. For this to be true in a language with function and constant symbols, you should also add the statements that $P$ is closed under all the function symbols and contains all the constants (so that $P$ picks out the domain of a substructure). The same idea works with the unary relation $P(x)$ replaced by any formula $\theta(x)$ in one free variable.

Comment: Could you be more precisely when it comes to $\{x+y|x,y\in X\}$  ? For example, hide an answer under spoiler - tomorrow I try to solve it on my own - in case of failure I use your spolier :)

Comment: Before, I try to solve (or unhide your hint) I would like understand solution for problem stated by me. What does it mean $P(x)$. It seems to be some magic-  you intruduce it. When it comes to relativiatiopn - I didn't managed to find it in google.  At intuition level, 1. and 2. are clear - however as I said $P$ is some magic.

Comment: I don't understand this. Is it true that $\phi$  is true only and only if $P(x)$ is true ? Then, for structure $\{x:P(x)\}$  $\phi$ is satisfable ?

Comment: Let me give you an example: Let $\phi$ be the sentence $\forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y)$. In a model of $\phi$, every element is related to some element by $R$. Then the relativized formula $\phi^P$ reads $\forall x\, (P(x)\rightarrow \exists y\, (P(y)\land R(x,y)))$. In a model of $\phi^P$, every element *of $P$* is related to some element *of $P$* by $R$. That is, a structure $A$ satisfies $\phi^P$ if and only if the substructure of $A$ with domain $P$ satisfies $\phi$. Anything else you like can happen outside of $P$.

Comment: It seems to me that using relativization you are able to choose substructures (and consequently submodels).  For example lets consider some model with $\mahthbb{N}$ as universum. Then if $P(1)$ we know that we choose substructure where $1$ is its element.  It is only intodcuction new unary symbol to choose subniversum.  However, relativization of formula $\phi$ makes it possible to conisder $phi$ in reference to $P$.    Am I right ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean. If you have more questions about relativization, maybe you should open a new question.

Comment: @ Alex Kruckman For the set $Y=\{2n : n\in X\}$ would your sentence simplify to $(\forall x\, Px)\wedge \varphi^{P}$? The following links to a related question where closure under multiplication is also discussed. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4492223/30229

Comment: @John The sentence $(\forall x\, P(x))\land \varphi^P$ is logically equivalent to $\varphi$. If $\varphi$ is a sentence with spectrum $X$, we can obtain the spectrum $\{2n: n\in X\}$ as I suggested in my answer: take the conjunction of $\varphi^P$ with the sentence asserting that $R$ is the graph of a bijection between $P$ and $\lnot P$. This ensures that $P$ is a model of $\varphi$ and $\lnot P$ has the same number of elements as $P$.

Comment: Do we need $\phi^{P}$ and $\phi^{Q}$ to have disjoint languages? For example, if $\phi$ is $\exists x\,\exists y\,Rxy$ then we replace $R$ for $S$ in the relativization with respect to $Q$.