# What are the closure properties of spectra?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are [spectra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_sentence), I can see that $X\cap Y$ and $X\cup Y$ are also spectra.

Is it always true that
$$X+Y:=\{n+m:n\in X,m\in Y\},$$
and
$$X\cdot Y:=\{n\cdot m:n\in X,m\in Y\}$$
are also spectra?

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496285/30229) related question for the special case $X^{2}=\{n^2:n\in X\}$.

---

My initial approach, say for $+$ was to use the construction in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489715/30229). Thus, we have the $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $A'$. Then we add two predicates to $\mathcal{L}$, one $Fx:\,x$ is in $X$, and and analogous $G$ for $Y$. Then define $B$ to be the sentence
$$((\neg\exists w\,Rzw)\wedge\exists x\,\exists y\,(Fx\wedge Gy\wedge Pxyz)).$$

Then consider $A'\wedge B$. But...

---

Edit: I found out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024134/there-is-given-spectrum-for-phi-find-such-psi-with-spectrum-with-special) is related, answering closure under addition.

Comment: (as an aside, I don't think your approach works, as it's not clear a priori how you can express "$x$ is in $X$" or "$y$ is in $Y$" in your language. certainly if you can give recursive definitions like you've done in your answer, then it would work. but I don't know whether every spectrum can be given such a definition; I believe it's an open problem whether $\mathbb{N}\setminus X$ is a spectrum for every spectrum $X$, so I at least don't think it's proven that every spectrum can be given such a definition)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I ran into. No way to define what belonging to a set meant in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. First let me give a helpful construction:

---

**Definition:** Let $L$ be a first-order language and $P$ a fresh unary predicate. For an $L$-formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, we are going to define a new sentence $\varphi^P(\bar{x})$, which I will call the relativization of $\varphi(\bar{x})$ to $P$, inductively as follows. If $\varphi(\bar{x})$ is atomic, we define $\varphi^P(\bar{x})$ as $\varphi(\bar{x})$. We then let relativization to $P$ distribute over conjunction and negation, so that $(\varphi(\bar{x})\wedge\psi(\bar{x}))^P=\varphi^P(\bar{x})\wedge\psi^P(\bar{x})$ and $(\neg\varphi)^P(\bar{x})=\neg(\varphi^P(\bar{x}))$. Finally, if $\varphi(\bar{x})$ is of form $\exists y\psi(\bar{x},y)$, then we define $\varphi^P(\bar{x})=\exists y(P(y)\wedge\varphi^P(\bar{x},y))$. $\blacksquare$

Okay, so what's the point of this construction? Well you can prove the following by induction on formulas, which I will leave as an exercise; recall that a language is "relational" if it has no function or constant symbols.

**Fact:** Let $M$ be an $L\cup\{P\}$-structure where $L$ is a relational first-order language and $P$ is a fresh unary predicate. Since $L$ is relational, any subset of $M$ can be naturally made into an $L$-structure; let $N$ denote the $L$-structure obtained by making $P^M\subseteq M$ into an $L$-structure in this way. Then for any $L$-sentence $\varphi$, we have $M\models\varphi^P$ if and only if $N\models\varphi$. $\blacksquare$

This is the sense in which $\varphi^P$ is a "relativization" of $\varphi$ to $P$, and it is a very useful construction throughout model theory!

---

With this construction done we can proceed. Let $\varphi$ and $\psi$ be sentences with spectrum $X$ and $Y$ respectively; without loss of generality we may assume that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are sentences in disjoint languages, say $K$ and $L$. Without loss of generality we may also assume these language are relational.

To obtain $X+Y$, we're going to construct a sentence $\theta$ such that (i) any model of $\theta$ is of form $M\sqcup N$, where $M$ is a model of $\varphi$ and $N$ is a model of $\psi$, and (ii) conversely any such disjoint union can be made into a model of $\theta$. This will give the desired result. To construct this sentence $\theta$, we will work in a new language $I=K\cup L\cup\{P,Q\}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are fresh unary predicates. Intuitively, our sentence $\theta$ will say that $P$ and $Q$ are disjoint, and that the realizations of $P$ give a model of $\varphi$ and that the realizations of $Q$ give a model of $\psi$. By our Fact above, we can do this by taking $\theta:=\forall x(P(x)\leftrightarrow\neg Q(x))\wedge\varphi^P\wedge\psi^Q$, and we are done.

To obtain $X\cdot Y$ as a spectrum, we need something slightly more elaborate. We're going to construct a sentence $\xi$ such that (i) every model of $\xi$ is of form $M\times N$ where $M$ is a model of $\varphi$ and $N$ is a model of $\psi$, and (ii) conversely every such product can be made into a model of $\xi$; this will again give the desired result. To do this, we're going to work in a language $J=K\cup L\cup\{P,Q\}\cup\{\pi,\sigma\}$, where $P$ and $Q$ are fresh unary predicates and $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are fresh unary function symbols. Morally $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are going to be "projection maps", and $P$ and $Q$ will be their respective images. Our sentence $\xi$ will thus say the following:

1. $\forall x[P(x)\leftrightarrow \exists y(x=\pi(y))]$ and $\forall x[Q(x)\leftrightarrow \exists y(x=\sigma(y))]$: this says that $P=\operatorname{im}(\pi)$ and $Q=\operatorname{im}(\sigma)$.
2. $\forall y\forall z[P(y)\wedge Q(z)\to\exists x(\pi(x)=y\wedge\sigma(x)=z)]$ and $\forall x,x'\left[x\neq x'\to\left(\pi(x)\neq\pi(x')\vee\sigma(x)\neq\sigma(x')\right)\right]$: this says that every pair $(y,z)\in P\times Q$ represents an element of the structure, and moreover that every element of the structure can be represented uniquely in this way.
3. $\varphi^P\wedge\psi^Q$: by the Fact, this says that $P$ is a model of $\varphi$, hence that $|P|\in X$, and that $Q$ is a model of $\psi$, hence that $|Q|\in Y$.

Now we are done! The three hypothesis guarantee that every model of $\xi$ has size $xy$ for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Conversely if $M\models\varphi$ and $N\models\psi$, then we can turn $M\times N$ into a $J$-structure as follows: pick any $a_0\in M$ and $b_0\in N$ and take $\pi^{M\times N}((a,b))=(a,b_0)$ and $\sigma^{M\times N}((a,b))=(a_0,b)$ for each $(a,b)\in M\times N$. Then, for a relation symbol $R(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in K$, define $R^{M\times N}$ as $\{((a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n)):(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^M\}$ and similarly for every relation symbol $S(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in L$. In this way $M\times N$ becomes a model of $\xi$, as needed.

Comment: Thank you. What if $X=Y$?, say for $X\cdot X=\{n^{2}:n\in X\}$ then $\varphi=\psi$ initially, but we simply re-name the predicates so that the languages are disjoint?

Comment: @John yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: Is the construction you describe in Marker's Model Theory?

Comment: @John indeed it is! Marker introduces it in his treatment of "Vaughtian pairs", which can be found starting on page 151. the construction is given at the top of page 152

Comment: The languages can have the identity predicate $=$ in common. Can they not?

Comment: @John yes, that's correct. most model theorists today take the convention that $=$ is a "non-logical symbol" in the same way that $\wedge,\exists,\neg$, and variables are, and hence that a first-order language consists of constant symbols, function symbols, and *non-equality* relation symbols. so under this convention equality does not lie in a first-order language to begin with

Comment: (@John incidentally, you need to do a similar relabelling of the language trick in order to prove that $X\cap Y$ is a spectrum whenever $X$ and $Y$ are. even if $X$ is the spectrum of $\varphi$ and $Y$ is the spectrum of $\psi$ there is no guarantee that $X\cap Y$ is the spectrum of $\varphi\wedge\psi$ unless $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are in disjoint languages. for example, suppose $R(x)$ is a unary relation symbol, and $\varphi=\forall x R(x)$ and $\psi=\forall x\neg R(x)$. then $\varphi$ and $\psi$ both have spectrum $\mathbb{N}$ but $\varphi\wedge\psi$ has spectrum $\varnothing$)

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. Closure of intersections and unions was simple.

Comment: (@John oh I know! but since you said in your post had no problem with those cases but then were asking me about the relabelling of the language trick I just wanted to make sure you were aware of that point since it's easy to overlook :) ... 
as an even further aside, note that you _don't_ need to relabel the languages for the $X\cup Y$ case)

Comment: Oh, I found your comment quite pertinent :)

Comment: @ Atticus Stonestrom If we restrict the language to having only predicates, is there a simpler way to show that if a set $X$ is a spectrum, then $X\cdot X$ (see my first comment above) is also a spectrum.

Comment: (@John so, just to make sure, you mean $\{n^2:n\in X\}$ rather than $\{mn:m,n\in X\}$? there may be, but I don't see an easier way off the top of my head. in fact my gut instinct is that that set might require a *more* elaborate argument. eg if we want to modify the argument in my post to obtain that set, we'd need to do something like adding a unary function symbol $f$ and an axiom that the restriction of $f$ to $P$ gives a bijection $P\to Q$)

Comment: (@John of course just because I don't see an easier way doesn't mean that one doesn't exist :) . worth asking as a separate question perhaps!)

Comment: @ Atticus Stonestrom I was checking Marker's book, and he defines $\varphi^{P}$ as $Px_{1}\wedge\ldots\wedge Px_{n}\wedge\varphi$ for $\varphi$ atomic. You define differently. Is there a reason? I have checked other books, and your definition is what they use.

Comment: @John indeed it makes no difference; with either definition you can prove the key property that, for every $L$-formula $\phi(\bar{x})$ and tuple $\bar{a}$ from $N$, we have $N\models\phi(\bar{a})$ iff $M\models\phi^P(\bar{a})$. I think Marker writes it that way just to drive home the point that we only will be thinking about the truth value of these relativized formulas evaluated on tuples from the substructure in question. (on a different note, note that Marker omits a tiny detail here, namely he forgets to require the language to be relational)

Comment: Why must the language be relational?

Comment: @John if it's not relational, then there is no guarantee that arbitrary subsets can be naturally made into substructures. (for example, if the subset is not closed under a certain function, or doesn't contain a constant, then it's not a substructure.) so in the sentence right before the statement of Lemma 4.3.37 Marker should say "An easy induction shows that if $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ *is a substructure* ...". admittedly this is a very pedantic point :) (and, looking back on it now, you could probably argue that it's clear from context, so feel free to ignore what I said :D)

Comment: @ Atticus Stonestrom. Good point. I thought I was missing something and it may have had to do with the concept of relativization. The texts I have consulted state the definition for any language.

Comment: I ended up taking your your suggestion and asked about $X\cdot X$ as a separate question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496285/if-x-is-a-spectrum-then-x-cdot-x-is-a-spectrum

Answer (score 2):

Following the lead (and notation) of Atticus Stonestrom's answer above, I wanted to look at a language having only predicates for the case of multiplication.

Consider the language $J=K\cup L\cup\{P,Q,H\}$, where the predicates $P$ and $Q$ are as before, but $H$ is a new ternary predicate. Then $\xi$ will be the conjunction of the following clauses:

1. $(\forall x\,(Px\Rightarrow\neg Qx)\wedge(Qx\Rightarrow\neg Px))\wedge\varphi^{P}\wedge\psi^{Q}$
2. $\forall x\,\forall y\,((Px\wedge Qy)\Rightarrow\exists z\,\forall t\,(Hxyt\Leftrightarrow (z=t)))$
3. $\forall z\,((\exists x\,\exists y\,\forall t\,((Pt\Leftrightarrow (x=t))\wedge(Qt\Leftrightarrow (y=t))))\wedge Hxyz)$

$\mathrm{Spectrum}(\xi)=X\cdot Y$, as desired.

Comment: indeed, this approach also works! there is a certain precise sense called [bi-interpretability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) in which your approach is "the same" as the one in my post. without worrying about the exact details, here's the rough idea:

Comment: given a model of your theory, you can define unary functions $\pi$ and $\sigma$ by taking $\pi(z)$ to be the unique $x$ such that there exists $y$ with $Hxyz$, and taking $\sigma(z)$ to be the unique $y$ such that there exists $x$ with $Hxyz$; this will then give a model of the theory in my post

Comment: conversely, given a model of the theory in my post, you can define the predicate $Hxyz$ by taking it to hold iff $\pi(z)=x$ and $\sigma(z)=y$, and then this will give a model of your theory

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Very interesting. There also seems to be a relationship between relativization and many-sorted logics and structures.

Comment: yes – that's absolutely right!! you can use relativization to reduce multi-sorted structures with finitely many sorts to single-sorted ones in a "lossless" way (I don't mean that in a precise sense, but rather in a "moral" one) which can simplify a lot of arguments!