# Expressing same size each equivalence class and this size is the same in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

The language is required to be relational and contains equality and two binary predicates $R$ and $S$.

Having expressed that $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations, each with more than one equivalence class, and partitioning our universe into *rows* and *columns* so that the intersection of each row and column consists of exactly one element, **how can I express that all $R$-equivalence classes (respectively for $S$) have the same size, and this size is the same for both equivalence relations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already done part of this. Let $\rho$ be the number of $R$-classes and let $\sigma$ be the number of $S$-classes. If every $S$-class intersects every $R$-class exactly once, then every $S$-class has size $\rho$. Similarly, every $R$-class has size $\sigma$.

So all the $R$-classes have the same size, and all the $S$-classes have the same size. But this does **not** mean that $\rho=\sigma$. Indeed, consider an $a\times b$ array with $a\not=b$: each column intersects each row exactly once and vice versa. In fact, the additional property you want **cannot be expressed in a first-order way at all**. This can be seen by a compactness/Lowenheim-Skolem argument: think about the behavior of an "$\infty$-by-$\infty$-array."

(That said, if you can get away with expanding your language a bit, this can be escaped: consider adding a unary predicate symbol $P$ and a sentence saying that $P$ intersects each row exactly once *and* each column exactly once.)

Comment: I don't quite understand why it is not expressible if the language only has $=$, $R$ and $S$. I will think about that. Regarding the unary predicate $P$, what is the intuitive idea behind what $P$ means, and how does it relate to the size being the same? I guess the sentence itself would be $$\forall x\,\exists y\,\exists z\,\forall s\,\forall t\,(Px\Rightarrow ((Rxs\Leftrightarrow (y=s))\wedge(Sxt\Leftrightarrow (z=t))))$$

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see the Compactness argument. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @John Re: your first comment, think of $P$ as the "diagonal" of the array: the only way we can hit each column exactly once and each row exactly once is if the array is square. Your formulation isn't right since it doesn't ever require $P$ to hold: try "For all $x$ there are unique (not-necessarily-distinct) $a,b$ in $P$ such that $aRx$ and $bSx$."

Comment: Re: your second comment, here's one way to do it (not using compactness at all in fact): show that an $\omega\times\omega$-array is an elementary substructure of a $\kappa\times\lambda$-array whenever $\kappa,\lambda$ are infinite (this is trivial via Lowenheim-Skolem), and now just take $\kappa\not=\lambda$. If you want to pay attention to only finite models, then you **can** actually do this with a set of sentences (for each $n$ have a sentence saying "If there are at least $n$ $R$-classes then there are at least $n$ $S$-classes") but not with a single sentence.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber. Ah I see it now. $P$ says our universe has a diagonal. I think one of my problems is that I do not think thoroughly enough in English the properties that I need the model to have. Then $\forall x\,\exists y\,\exists z\,(Py\wedge Pz\wedge Rxy\wedge Sxz)$ is what it should be.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber. Re; For the finite case, if it could be expressed that $\rho=\sigma$ then, a model would also satisfy the additional "if there are at least..." sentences. But the finiteness of the model would then imply a maximum of the size of $R$ or $S$ classes, and thus there would be models with $m\cdot k$ elements, with $m\neq k$ and both larger than the maximum class size. This is a contradiction. Thank you very much for your help :)