# Relativizing with respect to $P$ and $\neg P$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492223/what-are-the-closure-properties-of-spectra/4492253?noredirect=1#comment9433782_4492253) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024134/there-is-given-spectrum-for-phi-find-such-psi-with-spectrum-with-special) questions, relativization occurs with respect to new unary preicates $P$ and $Q$. For example, if the sets $X$ and $Y$ are [spectra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_sentence), say of the $L$-sentence $\varphi$ and the $K$-sentence $\psi$, respectively (where $L$ and $K$ are disjoint relational first order languages). Then the set
$$X+Y=\{\mbox{$m+n$ : $m\in X$ and $n\in Y$}\}$$
is the spectrum of the $L\cup K\cup\{P,Q\}$-sentence
$$\varphi^{P}\wedge\psi^{Q}\wedge (\forall x\,(Px\Leftrightarrow\neg Qx)),$$
were $P$ and $Q$ are new unary predicates, and $\varphi^{P}$ and $\psi^{Q}$ are the relativizations of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to $P$ and $Q$, respectively.

**Question: Could we simply relativize with respect to $P$ and $\neg P$. That is, $Q$ is simply $\neg P$? The sentence would become $\varphi^{P}\wedge\psi^{\neg P}$. But it seems there may be circumstances when this is not satisfiable, as we have the predicate $P$ in common. Or, where else is the pitfall?**

Comment: You absolutely can relativize to $\neg P$ instead of $Q$! The only pitfall, if it can be called that, is that it generalizes less easily to combining *three* or more spectra at once in this way (for that we can use three unary relation symbols and add a sentence saying that they partition the domain). And even that isn't really a thing, since $x_1+x_2+x_3=(x_1+x_2)+x_3$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Good, I though that would be the case after trying to find a counterexample for a while. Then $\mathrm{Spectrum}(\varphi^{P}\wedge\psi^{\neg P})=X+Y$. Also the sentences whose spectrum is $X\cdot Y$ given in the answers to the first linked question simplify a bit with $Q$ as $\neg P$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: (just as an aside, I just used two different predicates $P$ and $Q$ because I thought it would make the notation easier to follow – sorry if it caused any confusion!)